# multiple join values ​into one list in Fastapi

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, fastapi

How to combine multiple values ​​of the same id through join into one list in fastapi?

At the moment I am getting the following:

```json
[
  {
    "product_id": 1,
    "model": "model_1",
    "image": "catalog/product/blabla.jpg",
    "price": 5800,
    "quantity": 999,
    "name": "name_1"
  },
  {
    "product_id": 1,
    "model": "model_1",
    "image": "catalog/product/blabla.jpg",
    "price": 5800,
    "quantity": 999,
    "name": "name_2"
  },
  {
    "product_id": 1,
    "model": "model_1",
    "image": "catalog/product/blabla.jpg",
    "price": 5800,
    "quantity": 999,
    "name": "name_3"
  }

]
```

But I can't get it to look like this:

```json
[
  {
    "product_id": 1,
    "model": "model_1",
    "image": "catalog/product/blabla.jpg",
    "price": 5800,
    "quantity": 999,
    "name": ["name_1", "name_2", "name_3"]
  }
]
```

My ORM currently looks like this:

**orm.py**

```py
def get_product_by_id(product_id: int, db: Session):
    return db.query(OcProduct.product_id, OcProduct.model, OcProduct.image, OcProduct.price, OcProduct.quantity, OcStockStatu.name, OcOptionValueDescription.name)\
        .join(OcStockStatu, OcProduct.stock_status_id == OcStockStatu.stock_status_id)\
        .join(OcProductOptionValue, OcProductOptionValue.product_id == product_id)\
        .join(OcOptionValueDescription, OcOptionValueDescription.option_value_id == OcProductOptionValue.option_value_id)\
        .filter(OcProduct.product_id == product_id).all()
```

**product.py**

```py
@router.get("/{product_id}")
def get_detail_product(product_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    product = orm_product.get_product_by_id(product_id, db)
    ....
    return product
```

Here is the model code I am working with at the moment.
The model was not created by me, I just work with the finished part

**models.py**

```py
class OcProduct(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'oc_product'
    __table_args__ = (
        Index('extra', 'status', 'date_available'),
    )

    product_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    model = Column(String(64), nullable=False)
    quantity = Column(Integer, nullable=False, server_default=text("'0'"))
    stock_status_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    image = Column(String(255))
    price = Column(DECIMAL(15, 4), nullable=False, server_default=text("'0.0000'"))  
    status = Column(TINYINT(1), nullable=False, server_default=text("'0'"))
    ......
    viewed = Column(Integer, nullable=False, server_default=text("'0'"))


class OcStockStatu(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'oc_stock_status'

    stock_status_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    language_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(32), nullable=False)

class OcProductOptionValue(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'oc_product_option_value'

    product_option_value_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_option_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    product_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    option_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    option_value_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    quantity = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    price = Column(DECIMAL(15, 4), nullable=False)
    ....

class OcOptionValueDescription(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'oc_option_value_description'

    option_value_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    language_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    option_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(128), nullable=False)
```

Comment: If you haven't already, look into setting up [SQLAlchemy relationships](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html) for your database relations. Then, change your query to something like `product = db.query(OcProduct).filter(...).scalar()`. Then you should be able to access e.g. your stock status as `product.stock_status`. If you share your SQLAlchemy models, I can provide a full example.

Comment: Oh sure. I added you the code of the file with the models.

I segenerated this file through sqlacodegen, as I am already working with the created database. the database was also created automatically by the CMS itself